# How to change the keyboard to numeric for particular fields in webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I need the keyboard change automatically from normal to numeric keyboard only for particular fields such as phone number, ZipCode etc. is foucssed.
I can be able to enter the details in fields in webview.
Can i make this possible in java code or html page design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add such types of inputs in html

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

this should opens numeric keyboard

Comment: Not working for me, input type="number" opens the default keyboard on Android webview.